# Is there an alternative for Excel2Latex in Mac OS X?

Tags: tables, excel2latex

When I try to export a table to latex, the Excel does not allow to copy the code. I tried with Excel 2016 and last version 16.25. I don't know if the problem is the plugin or app.

Answer (score 2):

Spreadsheets since the dawn of time (and there were companies before Microsoft) have at their simplest exported data in comma separated fields as finame.csv (no fancy colours or shading to mess about with} and as plain text easy to import and / or manipulate.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\begin{document}
\csvautotabular{exportdata.csv}
\end{document}
```

Try the above with a simple block of data exported as csv to exportdata.csv in your working folder to see how it works. Note there are several other packages to try if that is too simple.

For those who like to see a working version without using real files mwe is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{example.csv}
column1,widgets,whatever 3
Item 1,4,Made with pride
Item 2,99,Made in Britain
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\csvautotabular{example.csv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, it is helpful.